# Google Chrome's Javascript console keyboard shortcuts

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to debug my javascript application using **Google Chrome 3**'s developer tools. Everything fine and ok, until I actually want to start debugging. I can set breakpoints etc., but I don't want to debug using a mouse but using keyboard.

In Firefox + Firebug I can use <kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>F11</kbd> and <kbd>F8</kbd> for stepping over, into and run debugged script.

**Are there any keyboard shortcuts in Google Chrome's Javascript console window**?

System configuration (if relevant):

- Windows Server 2008 R2 (would probably work the same in Windows 7)
- Google Chrome 3.0.195.21

**Edit**
I investigated this issue even further and it turns out to be some sort of a bug, because when I restart Chrome, <kbd>F8</kbd>, <kbd>F10</kbd> and <kbd>F11</kbd> work as expected (same as Firebug).

Comment: The answer is ESC key.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

<kbd>F8</kbd> - Run

<kbd>F10</kbd> - Step over

<kbd>F11</kbd> - Step into

Works for me

Comment: No definitely doesn't work in Chrome 3. F11 is browser universal Full screen shortcut

Comment: Yes, browser universal for when the browser window itself is focused but not when the debugger is focused.

Comment: Strange. In my case even Developer Tools window fullscreens. Tried F11 with separate window as well as docked into browser. Same behaviour.

Comment: Windows Server 2008 R2 which would probably be equal to Windows 7.

Comment: Perhaps you can submit a bug to Google :)

Comment: For me it works *sometimes* (Chrome 12.0.742.91). All of a sudden the F11 keys maps to "debugger window fullscreen", so I can't use it to step into a function call any more. Didn't figure out when that happens. The other keys also don't work any more in that case.

Answer (score 59):

To see the full list of shortcuts for the currently installed version:
in chrome open the Developer Tools <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and then open shortcut help <kbd>?</kbd>.[image]

Edit: To get list of shortcuts, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>?</kbd> when you are in other than 'console' tab, like 'Elements' or 'Resources'

Answer (score 11):

In addition to Chris Tek's answer:

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> - Step Out Of

Comment: That's a helpful one. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the full list of shortcuts for the latest version of Chrome Developer Tools:

http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/shortcuts.html

Answer (score 0):

Toggle Breakpoint: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, pretty essential!

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

A much better reference of Chrome DevTools shortcuts can be found here (https://shortcutref.com/chrome-dev-tools).

This page only shows the relevant shortcuts (level, OS, category) and has short and precise descriptions.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.