# customize chrome developer tool javascript debugger keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, keyboard-shortcuts, customization, javascript-debugger

I can't believe that neither a Google or SO search has turned up a definitive answer or even much discussion for this, but:

Is it possible to edit/customize keyboard shortcuts in the Google Chrome JavaScript debugger?  if so, how?

I'm used to Eclipse's <kbd>F5</kbd>/<kbd>F6</kbd>/<kbd>F7</kbd>/<kbd>F8</kbd> debugger step into/over/out of/resume keys, and want the same bindings in Google Chrome.  <kbd>F10</kbd>/<kbd>F11</kbd> are default Expose keys for OSX and therefore not ideal for debugger control.

I'm open to unorthodox solutions, e.g. Quicksilver/AppleScript.

Related, but not-quite-helpful, pages:

- [Google Chrome's Javascript console keyboard shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437412/)
- [Chrome Keyboard Shortcuts Documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/shortcuts.html)

Comment: nope.  i did find this though: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/shortcuts

Comment: and also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437412/google-chromes-javascript-console-keyboard-shortcuts  but nothing on editing the shortcuts.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the update.  It's too bad they don't allow for this.  You'd think a lot of people switching from Eclipse to chrome-dev would want something like this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Chrome Developer Tools keyboard shortcut customization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14661878/google-chrome-developer-tools-keyboard-shortcut-customization)

Comment: @PaulSweatte did you notice I already marked that other question as a possible dupe of this one?...two years ago ;)

Comment: DevTools tech writer / developer advocate here. As of today this feature still doesn't exist. Getting it native in DevTools is probably just a matter of prioritization. Let the DevTools team know it's important to you by starring [issue #174309](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=174309).

Comment: Still doesn't exist in 2021.

Answer (score 14):

Related:

Addy has started an issue 'Ability to customize keyboard shortcuts/key bindings for DevTools':
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=174309

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! Cross-linked.

Comment: That issue just got updated as "Status: Available".  So I imagine we'll start seeing something rollout soon.

Comment: Looking forward to that day we can comfortably show/hide Console with one hand.

Comment: @LeoTM: show/hide console with `Esc`.  Also: status changed on that to 'Assigned' on July 8

Comment: @ebpa `Esc` only applies once the console is open, not straight from browser. Nice just starred the issue, will keep checking up.

Answer (score 9):

There's now an experimental setting to allow you to customise shortcuts!

Click on the settings button in DevTools:

[image: DevTools settings]

Then Experiments, search for "key" and ticking Enable keyboard shortcut editor will add the Shortcuts item:

[image]

You can now customise shortcuts and there's a handy one for if you use VS Code:

[image]

You'll have to reload DevTools for it to take effect.

Comment: Weirdly this just doesn't seem to work *at all*. Or maybe it just doesn't accept certain hotkeys? I tried both cmd+2 and ctr+2 for "step over" and even after restart it just doesn't respond at all. The GUI shows the new hotkey in the tooltips though..

Comment: Works for me and I guess a few others if it was upvoted :) have you tried F10 for step over?

Comment: The default shortcuts work yes. But changing them? Nope. Had to use karabiner to map the keys I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

I did this with [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/xml.html.en). I'm using a full size keyboard (<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F19</kbd> keys) so I mapped them to <kbd>F13</kbd> to <kbd>F16</kbd>. This way the layout of the keys matches the layout of the buttons in Chrome. Keymap file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <appdef>
    <appname>CHROME</appname>
    <equal>com.google.Chrome</equal>
  </appdef>

  <item>
    <name>CHROMEDEBUGGINGKEY</name>
    <appendix>This maps the F13-F16 keys to Chrome debugging keys</appendix>
    <identifier>private.swap_chrome_to_debug_settings</identifier>
    <only>CHROME</only>
    <!--<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::SPACE, KeyCode::TAB</autogen>-->
    <autogen>
      __KeyToKey__
      KeyCode::F13, KeyCode::F8
    </autogen>
    <autogen>
      __KeyToKey__
      KeyCode::F14, KeyCode::F10
    </autogen>
    <autogen>
      __KeyToKey__
      KeyCode::F15, KeyCode::SEMICOLON, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L
    </autogen>
    <autogen>
      __KeyToKey__
      KeyCode::F16, KeyCode::SEMICOLON, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L,
    </autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Answer (score 2):

Chrome Shortcut Manager didn't work for me, but using KeyRemap4MacBook did. More details here: [Google Chrome Developer Tools keyboard shortcut customization on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14661878/google-chrome-developer-tools-keyboard-shortcut-customization/21053814#21053814)

Comment: Note that KeyRemap4MacBook has since been renamed to Karabiner.  In addition to the link given in this answer, see other answers on this page that reference Karabiner, for similar solutions on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is using [Autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com/), a tool that I use for shortcuts in any app.

I make and run an .ahk script like this:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1 ; Chrome browser
F2::Send, ^b ; toggle breakpoint (Ctrl+b)
^b::Send, ^m ; use Ctrl+b for something else
```

It's simple: only when Chrome browser window is active, override F2 key and simulate Ctrl+b, which is official Chrome shortcut to toggle breakpoint.

I actually run my ahk script when Windows starts, so shortcuts are always active.

You can add more shortcuts. You can use different browser or app.
One thing that I can't improve yet is listening for shortcuts only when web developer tools in browser are active, maybe there's a way.

Comment: That's dope. I use autohotkey for a bunch of things like that. I used the beginning of your code to replace a double right-click with the element inspector (original shortcut is ctrl + shift + c). I'm gonna save a decent amount of time!

If anyone wanna try that out: 

`#IfWinActive ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1 ; Chrome browser
$RButton::
SetTimer , Fast, 175
Fast_Count+=1
return 
Fast:
if (Fast_Count>=2){
 Send, ^+c
 Fast_Count = 0
 } else if (Fast_Count=1) {
 MouseClick, right
 Fast_Count = 0
 }else{
 Fast_Count = 0
}
return`

Answer (score 1):

There are key mappers for every OS which allow overriding default key combinations; here are a few:

- Windows

  - Texter
  - AutoHotKey
- OSX

  - xType
- Linux

  - AutoKey

Fork and extend the Chrome Shortcut Manager for native functionality.

**References**

- [Texter](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/texter_portable)
- [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)
- [xType](http://lifehacker.com/5885264/xtype-is-a-simple-free-text-expansion-tool-for-the-mac)
- [AutoKey](http://code.google.com/p/autokey/)
- [Chrome Shortcut Manager](https://github.com/caffeine1664/chrome-shortcut-manager)

Comment: This looks promising!  Thanks for the heads-up.  Marking this as answered, pending it actually does what it claims to (haven't tested it yet).

Comment: This doesn't support rebinding the developer tools.

Comment: @ericsoco It does not look like the answer - does not work for me. If you managed to make it work for dev tools, could you tell us how?

Comment: Agree, that this does not allow to customize DevTools shortcuts. Plus, using an extension that was last time updated 5,5 year ago (December 2009) isn't something, that I'd like to do.

Comment: @trejder nope, I was trigger-happy on the acceptance. Still haven't found a good answer. There are some key mapper tools out there that are not application-specific, but that's more work than I think is justified for this specific need.

Comment: @raacer http://superuser.com/questions/980733/how-to-send-using-autokey-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that worked for me was to disable the shortcuts at the OS level (or change them to something else).

In OSX, you can go to `System Preferences > keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts` and change/disable the shortcuts that you need to work in Chrome.

Comment: This has no effect in Chrome Developer Tools.

Comment: @jcollum can you elaborate on what is missing? This is all the information that I have and would like to know a better solution if there is one.

Comment: Well you need to go to App Shortcuts after opening Keyboard Shortcuts. Then... do what? Don't know. That's why it's incomplete.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. I don't agree, though, so I'll leave it as it is. It seems very obvious to me how to do it once you open the shortcuts window.

Comment: In Mojave, I see no applications listed in App Shortcuts. This is such a pain. :(

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @jcollum's answer, here is another Karabiner [private.xml](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/xml.html.en) definition.  This one imitates my IntelliJ key bindings.  See also [keyboard shortcut toggling](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/191244/89069) answer on apple.stackexchange.com.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>Custom via private.xml</name>

    <appdef>
      <appname>ChromeLike</appname>
      <equal>com.google.Chrome</equal>
      <equal>com.vivaldi.Vivaldi</equal>
      <prefix>org.epichrome.app.</prefix>
    </appdef>
    <item>
      <name>Remap debugger keys in Chrome (IntelliJ)</name>
      <appendix>Change consumer keys to function keys matching IntelliJ shortcuts</appendix>
      <identifier>private.app_chromelike_switch_consumer_to_intellij_debugger</identifier>
      <only>ChromeLike</only>
      <autogen>__KeyToKey__ ConsumerKeyCode::MUSIC_PREV, ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::F11</autogen> <!-- F7 Step Into -->
      <autogen>__KeyToKey__ ConsumerKeyCode::MUSIC_PLAY, ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::F10</autogen> <!-- F8 Step Over -->
      <autogen>__KeyToKey__ ConsumerKeyCode::MUSIC_PLAY, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L, KeyCode::F11, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L</autogen> <!-- S-F8 Step Out -->
      <autogen>__KeyToKey__ ConsumerKeyCode::KEYBOARDLIGHT_HIGH, ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::F11, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L</autogen> <!-- F6 Step Out -->
      <autogen>__KeyToKey__ ConsumerKeyCode::MUSIC_NEXT, ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::F8</autogen> <!-- F9 Resume -->
    </item>

  </item>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @jcollum's answer, here is yet another Karabiner [private.xml](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/xml.html.en) definition, this one implementing the specific Eclipse key bindings in the original question.  See also [keyboard shortcut toggling](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/191244/89069) answer on apple.stackexchange.com.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>Custom via private.xml</name>

    <appdef>
      <appname>ChromeLike</appname>
      <equal>com.google.Chrome</equal>
      <equal>com.vivaldi.Vivaldi</equal>
      <prefix>org.epichrome.app.</prefix>
    </appdef>
    <item>
      <name>Remap debugger keys in Chrome (Eclipse)</name>
      <appendix>Change consumer keys to function keys matching Eclipse shortcuts</appendix>
      <identifier>private.app_chromelike_switch_consumer_to_eclipse_debugger</identifier>
      <only>ChromeLike</only>
      <autogen>__KeyToKey__ ConsumerKeyCode::KEYBOARDLIGHT_LOW,  ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::F11</autogen> <!-- F5 Step Into -->
      <autogen>__KeyToKey__ ConsumerKeyCode::KEYBOARDLIGHT_HIGH, ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::F10</autogen> <!-- F6 Step Over -->
      <autogen>__KeyToKey__ ConsumerKeyCode::MUSIC_PREV, ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::F11, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L</autogen> <!-- F7 Step Out -->
      <autogen>__KeyToKey__ ConsumerKeyCode::MUSIC_PLAY, ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::F8</autogen> <!-- F8 Resume -->
    </item>

  </item>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my [Autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) Script for mapping Chrome Debugger Shortkeys

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1 ; targetting only Chrome browser
F8::Send, {F10}   ; chrome debugger next step   map key F8      to chrome devtools F10
F9::Send, {F8}    ; chrome debugger continue    map key F9      to chrome devtools F8
F7::Send, {F11}   ; chrome debugger step in     map key F7      to chrome devtools F11 
^F7::Send, +{F11} ; chrome debugger step out    map key Strg+F7 to chrome devtools Shift+F11
```

If you want to include the snippet in your existing ahk script, add it to the end of the script.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody uses Ubuntu, setting a global shortcut is probably the best solution for the moment. Here's what worked for me:

1. Install xcape (https://github.com/alols/xcape). For Debian based systems you can run:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install git gcc make pkg-config libx11-dev libxtst-dev libxi-dev
   git clone https://github.com/alols/xcape.git
   cd xcape
   make
   sudo make install
   ```
2. Run the following command to map for ex. F6 to the dev tools shortcut:

   ```
   xcape -e 'F6=Control_L|Shift_L|I'
   ```
3. Set the shortcuts you prefer and put the relative commands in your `.bash_profile` for permanent results