# Google Chrome Developer Tools keyboard shortcut customization on Mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, customization, developer-tools

I use Firefox Firebug to debug but would switch to Google chrome if I could customize the keyboard shortcuts.

I need to activate and hide the 'developer tools > inspect Element', 1000 times a day.
Trying to type <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> with one hand, it's a nightmare. I navigate with the mouse

The extension 'Shortcut Manager' has limited built in options. The ability to add Javascripts doesn't help me, where would you start on a task like this?

Because 'inspect Element' has no presence in the Mac menu, I can't even target it that way.

Any ideas?

Comment: install firebug for chrome!

Comment: There is no firebug plugin, only firebug Lite (a pure JS application running within a page) Bleh! for obvious reasons. Plus nobody is maintaining Firebug Lite at the moment. Double bleh!

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192714/customize-chrome-debugger-keyboard-shortcuts

Answer (score 13):

There's a simple way to do this without any add-ons.

To open Chrome dev tools with just F12 on a Mac:
Open up **System Preferences** > **Keyboard**. Check the box marked "**Use all F1, F2 etc. keys as standard function keys**".

Then go to the Shortcuts tab, and select **App Shortcuts** from the side menu. Make a new shortcut by hitting the **+** button, and select Google Chrome as the application. 
In the **Menu Title** input, type **Developer Tools** and then simply type **F12** (or your own preferred shortcut) in the **Keyboard Shortcut** input.

Comment: This is the best answer totally ;)

Comment: AMAZING!  And, so you can also add a line with "Reload This Page" for `F5`.

Answer (score 5):

For Mac: `System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts tab > Application Shortcuts left-tab >` [plus button] Application: Chrome ... Menu title: Developer Tools (or equivalent) ... Keyboard Shortcut: F12 (if you like it like Firebug)

hope this answers your q :)

EDIT: I realize you're referring to "inspect element" which I believe on my version of Chrome is `cmd+opt+C` instead of your reference of `cmd+shift+C` (cmd+opt+c is it that hard?). Regardless, I'm +1 on having customized key commands in Chrome, as I dislike the cmd+1, 2, 3, etc when in Developer Tools when I'm trying to browse tabs and get stuck.

Comment: Nope, it's not that hard. But a little harder. My solution makes very easy and less error prone for me. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve my problem by using the program 'KeyRemap4MacBook' https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/index.html.en

I keep the default Chrome shortcuts and just alias them with the short I am used too.

To achieve this I had to click on the 'Misc & Uninstall' button. Then by 'Custom Settings' click the 'Open private.xml' button. My contents of this file are shown below.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <appdef>
        <appname>CHROME</appname>
        <equal>com.google.Chrome</equal>
    </appdef>


    <item>
        <name>CHROMETOFIREFOX</name>
        <appendix>this is to remap chrome inspect element to Command + `</appendix>
        <identifier>private.swap_chrome_to_ff_settings</identifier>
        <only>CHROME</only>
        <autogen>
        __KeyToKey__
        KeyCode::BACKQUOTE, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L | ModifierFlag::NONE,
        KeyCode::C, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L | ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L
        </autogen>
    </item>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  For more examples of Karabiner mappings, see the answers to this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8192714/2562319 .  Includes mappings for F13-F16 http://stackoverflow.com/a/30926295/2562319 , IntelliJ http://stackoverflow.com/a/37977748/2562319 , and Eclipse http://stackoverflow.com/a/37977899/2562319 .

Answer (score 0):

`Opt` + `Cmd` + `j` opens DevTools Console.
It may be an easier combination (because 2 are adjacent, and 1 is other hand)