# How do you change/customize the keyboard shortcut for Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, google-chrome-devtools

I especially want to change the script debugging keys (F8 for Step over, F9 for Step into, etc.).

Scripts, extensions, hacks, any tips are welcomed! Thanks.

Some info: Running Chrome 26.0.1410.65 (latest as of writing) and Mac OS X 10.8.3.

[image]

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192714/customize-chrome-debugger-keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [customize chrome developer tool javascript debugger keyboard shortcuts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192714/customize-chrome-developer-tool-javascript-debugger-keyboard-shortcuts)

Comment: The answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69054641/257299

Answer (score -3):

Here is a [Shortcut Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortcut-manager/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf)
 try this, and let me know if it works for you. =)

Comment: it sucks with dev tools. and if you're not sure, better write a comment