# Shortcut for switching between tabs in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, browser, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

Is there a pre-built shortcut that allows you to switch tabs in a similar manner you would with browser tabs?:

<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>{</kbd>

<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>}</kbd>

Referring to these tabs below:

[image]

Looked on the dev tools [site](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/shortcuts) but to no avail. If there's not a shortcut available what would be an ideal shortcut combo that's readily available to the keyboard?

Comment: This website has a lot of commands for dev mode: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/shortcuts but I don't think there's a shortcut for switching between those tabs.

Comment: if you're working on sources tab, it has a console (so no need to switch to console tab)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

In the DevTools Settings under `Appearance` check off (Linux/Win) `Enable Ctrl + 1-9 shortcut to switch panels` or (Mac) `Enable Cmd/⌘ + 1-9 shortcut to switch panels`. This will turn on the ability to use `ctrl` or `cmd|⌘` switching just like tabs for the DevTools when they have focus.

Comment: For mac users it's `⌘ + 1-9` and not actually `Ctrl`.

Comment: As it would be for any Mac shortcuts.

Comment: @Garbee True, but the setting still words it as "Ctrl" on all platforms, oddly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I just added the Mac shortcuts. And next time, I encourage you to just to edit the answer and add it yourself. That is what StackOverflow is all about!

Answer (score 72):

Try this:

To go to left panel

> Ctrl + [

To go to right panel

> Ctrl + ]

For other panel shorcuts,

> Go to Developer options/tools then
>   Click on Settings or by pressing F1

[image: View Settings image]

> Then go to "Shortcuts" and scroll down to "All Panels"

[image: View Shorcuts image]

Comment: Great thanks. I'd just make a note in your answer that for mac users that instead of `ctrl` it's `cmd`.

Comment: Is there any way to change it?

Comment: @Jacob I think you are looking for following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192714/customize-chrome-developer-tool-javascript-debugger-keyboard-shortcuts Hope it helps!

Comment: For me, on ubuntu is Ctrl + ´ to go to the left.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to use the `⌘ + [` and `⌘ + ]` shortcuts to switch between DevTools tabs using a French QWERTY keyboard (on macOS).

On QWERTY, we need to press `⌥ + Shift + {` to type `[`, but in combination with the Command key, that would become `⌘ + ⌥ + Shift + {`. Not only is that almost impossible to type, but it also doesn't work.

It is not possible to redefine that keyboard shortcut in DevTools Shortcuts settings so I guess QWERTY users are out of luck unless someone knows a solution.