# Opera DevTools Keyboard Shortcuts - unable to type "[" or "]" due to german keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, opera, devtools

I am unable to type the square brackets into the DevTools console on my german keyboard.

Opera toggles through the Dev Panels because of the (hardcoded) shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>]</kbd>

On my german keyboard I need to type <kbd>ALT GR</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd> to get the "[" (or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>)

Is there any way to either change the default shortcut or disable this feature some how?

Comment: This is not an Opera shortcut (those would be defined in opera://settings/configureCommands) but a [Chrome DevTools shortcut](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/shortcuts) (since Opera uses Blink, like Chrome). Which would make this a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8192714/983430), though the answers there seem to imply you're stuck with current shortcuts until Google does something (unlikely...) or you need to resort to third-party solutions.

Comment: Inside Chrome I dont have this problem. There I can type any combination to get the square brackets (ALT GR or ALT + CTRL)