# Chrome Devtools console autocomplete key shortcut change

Tags: google-chrome, console, google-chrome-devtools

When I use the chrome devtools console, the Tab key is used to perform autocomplete when typing. Can this key be changed? I am impartial towards Enter since this is how Eclipse/Netbeans work. Is there an option / extension / some options file that would allow me to change that?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an option as of now. The chrome dev tools doesn't provide a way to customize the shortcuts. For more info refer to [customize chrome developer tool javascript debugger keyboard shortcuts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192714/)

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023 there is now an option for OP's original request of accepting autocomplete suggestions with the <kbd>enter</kbd> key.

In Chrome settings -> preferences -> "Accept autocomplete suggestion on Enter"

[image: Screenshot of Chrome devtools settings]